# SVG: same SVG image, different styles

Tags: image, svg

From a SVG image (like http://www.somerandomdude.com/work/iconic/), I would like to be able to use some CSS style to change the color of the image.

I just have this:

```
<image xlink:href="/icons/plus-alt.svg" x="20" y="4" height="16px" width="16px" />
```

Since the .svg file is containing a SVG element with a single PATH element, is there any way CSS can reach this PATH element?

If not, Would it be possible to copy and paste the PATH element as a "def" and reference it with the xlink:href attribute like this:

```
<image xlink:href="#plusImage" x="20" y="4" height="16px" width="16px" />
```

(I couldn't make it work)

Note that it would be possible to use the USE tag to reference the DEF but then you loose the very useful height/width attributes of the IMAGE tag.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: SVG images are not externally modifiable.

Comment: is there any reason why you cannot download the icon pack and edit the svg sources according to your needs? ianal, but the icon set is advertised as free to use. you could also add an `id` attribute to the icon (for the one in question you have the predefined `plus_x5F_alt`) and probably style it with a  rule like `#plus_x5F_alt { fill: #123456; }` (beware that i haven't tested this).

Comment: @collapsar: see http://jsfiddle.net/blindman/SJkB4/ , I can't get the CSS to be applied on the path.

Comment: so far i can only offer you a partial solution. your css goes in an external stylesheet with a selector on the proper descendant of the the `defs` element. to be seen online [here](http://collapsar.co.ohost.de/data/so.15513073.svg) and in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/JyNZk/) (non-functional as i do not know how to reference the css section of a fiddle by an url).  what's still missing is the hover pseudo class - that styling doesn't yet work.